# Matplotlib subplots_adjusts function not working

Tags: python, matplotlib

Why is my `plt.subplots_adjusts()` function not working in the following example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

if __name__ == "__main__":
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(3,1)
    for ax in axes:
        x = np.linspace(0, 1, 10)
        y = np.linspace(0, 2, 10)
        ax.plot(x, y)
    plt.subplots_adjust(right=.5)
    plt.show()
```

I simply want to add some space at the right.

Comment: Works for me. Can you show a screenshot of what you are seeing vs what you expect to see?

Comment: For me, the subplots always range the full width independent on what I say in my `subplots_adjust` function